# tls 1.2 in .net 4.7 not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ssl

I am trying to force TLS 1.2 on my login page.

I have installed .net 4.7.1. I checked this by going to the registry.

hkey_local_machine/software/Microsoft/NET Framework Setup/v4/full/release and the dword is 460805 per these instructions [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed)

I have also forced tls 1.2 through my global.asax file

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
End Sub
```

I also set the page up to use SSL in IIS and to use my company's cert.

Every time I access the page, Chrome states that I am using tls 1.0

[image: TLS results]

Windows Server 2008 R2

Any suggestions would be helpful, thank you very much

Comment: How about using [IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) on your website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it, Since it is server 2008 r2 I had to modify the registery to turn on tls 1.2. Here are the instructions lifted from this [blog](https://tecadmin.net/enable-tls-on-windows-server-and-iis/#)

Step 2: Enable TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2

2.1 Open registry on your server by running ‘regedit‘ in run window and navigate to below location.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols
2.2 Add the TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 keys under Protocols. It will looks like directories.

TLS-1

2.3 Now create two keys Client and Server under both TLS keys.

2.4 Now create the DWORD Values under Server and Client key as following

DisabledByDefault [Value = 0]
  Enabled [Value = 1]

Comment: Or use [IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) and have a nice UI for that.

Comment: @UweKeim nice, I didnt know that existed.

Comment: Is it only for .net applications? I am asking this because firefox is able to connect this service but not my .net application? its on win srv 2008 r2 sp1.

Comment: @MubasharAhmad This is only for .net application. It doesn't matter what browser you are using. TLS 1.2 is browser agnostic. I think you are confused about what is a .net application and connecting to it. If you post a qustion i would be able to help you better.

Comment: @gh9 I think you answered my question already. my question was if above registry change required for any application trying to connect to tls1.2 service or its just .net specific entries and only change the behavior of .net applications? I have made my application work on winSrv2008R2Sp1 by hard-coding tls12 version in code anyway. thanks